# Pandas: To prepare for a merge, how can I get the date/year formats of two large (1.3 million row) columns to match?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, cell

Hang with me, I'm new to pandas. To merge two large dataframes, I need to match a few hundred thousand rows by three columns. The year format in one df column is 'MM/DD/**YY** HH:MM', and in the other df column 'YY**YY**'. This is my merge command:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2,  how='left', left_on=['COL1','COL2','YEAR'], 
              right_on = ['COL1','COL2','DATE'])
```

The last two `YY` values match up across columns -- how can I standardize those so I can match these two?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a new column that matches the date format of the year column, then join on that new column. The first line creates a new column that has datetime objects in it, then the second line formats that datetime object as the four digit year string to match the other dataframe's year column.

`df2.new_date_col = [datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M') for x in df2.date_col]
df2.new_year_col = [x.strftime('%Y') for x in df2.new_date_col]`

Comment: Thanks! I created a workaround by splitting Excel columns and turning them all to text. I really appreciate the help, though!

Answer (score 0):

Using Excel, I used Data > Text to Columns, which let me separate by '/'. From there, I changed the format on the new YEAR columns to match (I chose 'text'), saved, and re-ran my original lines.